# HTTP ERROR in Python

Tags: python

I seem to be getting this error with urllib.request and it gives me this url error that i cant seem to fix.

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jarvis\Documents\Python Scripts\MultiCheck by Koala.py", line 133, in <module>
    Migration()
  File "C:\Users\Jarvis\Documents\Python Scripts\MultiCheck by Koala.py", line 116, in Migration
    rawdata_uuid = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 469, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 579, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 507, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: 42
```

The code im using is here is for a migration checker for a game:

```
def Migration():
url = "https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + einfos
rawdata = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
newrawdata = rawdata.read()
jsondata = json.loads(newrawdata.decode('utf-8'))
results = jsondata['id']
url = "https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/" + results
rawdata_uuid = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
newrawdata_uuid = rawdata_uuid.read()
jsondata_uuid = json.loads(newrawdata_uuid.decode('utf-8'))
try:
    results = jsondata_uuid['legacy']
    print ("Unmigrated")
except:
    print("Migrated")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid HTTP error 429 (Too Many Requests) python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786068/how-to-avoid-http-error-429-too-many-requests-python)

Comment: How do i fix this error

Comment: *All public APIs are rate limited so you are expected to cache the results. This is currently set at 600 requests per 10 minutes but this may change.* http://wiki.vg/Mojang_API

Answer (score -1):

Error 429 means: Too many requests. You seem to have hit a rate limit. The additional number gives are the seconds you have to wait for the limitation to be dropped. So, try again in 42s, or later.