# Scraping function works only on some computers (R)

Tags: r, shiny, python-requests

We are doing a project with a shiny app that involves scraping and downloading dataframes from a website. We have the following problem: It works on some computers and not others.
We have the same packages versions, and we did not do too many requests...
It is not linked with whether it is on windows of mac, as it works on some windows and some macs but not others.
Do you have any idea ? Could it be in the connexion settings ?
It is not linked with the wifi network, we tried on the same wifi...

Upon request here is the code and the error messages :

This function is the one we call directly:

```
scraping_function <- function(search_terms, subreddit, 
                               sort_by , time_frame){
  
  exctracted_link <- reddit_urls_mod(search_terms, subreddit, 
                                     sort_by , time_frame)
  
  exctracted_data <- reddit_content(exctracted_link[,5])
  
  exctracted_data[,13] <- cleaning_text_function(exctracted_data[,13])
  
  return(exctracted_data)
}
```

These are the functions that this function calls :

1. extracting the URLS:

```
reddit_urls_mod<- function (search_terms = "", subreddit = "",
                            sort_by = "", time_frame= "")
{

  if (subreddit == ""){
    subreddit <- NA
  }

  if (search_terms == ""){
    search_terms <- NA
  }

  if (!grepl("^[0-9A-Za-z]*$", subreddit) & !is.na(subreddit) ) {
    stop("subreddit must be a sequence of letter and number without special characters and spaces")
  }

  regex_filter = ""
  cn_threshold = 0
  page_threshold = 15
  wait_time = 1

  cached_links = data.frame(date = as.Date(character()),
                            num_comments = numeric(),
                            title = character(),
                            subreddit = character(),
                            URL = character(),
                            link = character())

  if (sort_by != "front_page"){

    if (!grepl("^comments$|^new$|^relevance$|^top$|^front_page$", sort_by)) {
      stop("sort_by must be either 'new', 'comments', 'top', 'relevance' or 'front_page'")
    }

    if (!grepl("^hour$|^day$|^week$|^month$|^year$|^all$", time_frame)) {
      stop("time_frame must be either 'hour', 'day', 'week', 'month', 'year or 'all'")
    }


    sterms = ifelse(is.na(search_terms), NA, gsub("\\s", "+",search_terms))

    subreddit = ifelse(is.na(subreddit), "", paste0("r/", gsub("\\s+","+", subreddit), "/"))

    sterms = ifelse(is.na(sterms), "", paste0("q=", sterms, "&restrict_sr=on&"))
    sterms_prefix = ifelse(sterms == "", "new", "search")
    time_frame_in = ifelse(is.na(search_terms), "", paste0("t=",time_frame,"&"))

    search_address = search_query = paste0("https://www.reddit.com/",
                                           subreddit, sterms_prefix,
                                           ".json?",
                                           sterms,time_frame_in,
                                           "sort=",
                                           sort_by)

  } else {
    if (is.na(subreddit)) {
      stop("if you choose sort_by = front_page please enter a subreddit")
    }

    search_address = search_query = paste0("https://www.reddit.com/r/",
                                           subreddit,
                                           ".json?")
  }

  next_page = index = ""
  page_counter = 0
  comm_filter = 10000
  while (is.null(next_page) == FALSE & page_counter < page_threshold &
         comm_filter >= cn_threshold & length(index) > 0) {
    search_JSON = tryCatch(RJSONIO::fromJSON(readLines(search_query,
                                                       warn = FALSE)), error = function(e) NULL)
    if (is.null(search_JSON)) {
      stop(paste("Unable to connect to reddit website or invalid subreddit entered"))
    } else if (length(search_JSON$data$children)==0){
      stop(paste("This search term returned no results or invalid subreddit entered"))
    } else {
      contents = search_JSON[[2]]$children
      search_permalink = paste0("http://www.reddit.com",
                                sapply(seq(contents), function(x) contents[[x]]$data$permalink))
      search_num_comments = sapply(seq(contents), function(x) contents[[x]]$data$num_comments)
      search_title = sapply(seq(contents), function(x) contents[[x]]$data$title)
      search_score = sapply(seq(contents), function(x) contents[[x]]$data$score)
      search_subreddit = sapply(seq(contents), function(x) contents[[x]]$data$subreddit)
      search_link = sapply(seq(contents), function(x) contents[[x]]$data$url)
      index = which(search_num_comments >= cn_threshold &
                      grepl(regex_filter, search_title, ignore.case = T,
                            perl = T))
      if (length(index) > 0) {
        search_date = format(as.Date(as.POSIXct(unlist(lapply(seq(contents), function(x) contents[[x]]$data$created_utc)),
                                                origin = "1970-01-01")), "%d-%m-%y")


        temp_dat = data.frame(date = search_date,
                              num_comments = search_num_comments,
                              title = search_title,
                              subreddit = search_subreddit,
                              URL = search_permalink,
                              link = search_link,
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[index,]

        cached_links = as.data.frame(rbind(cached_links,
                                           temp_dat))
        next_page = search_JSON$data$after
        comm_filter = utils::tail(search_num_comments,
                                  1)
        search_query = paste0(search_address, "&after=",
                              next_page)
        page_counter = page_counter + 1
      }
      Sys.sleep(min(2, wait_time))
    }
  }
  final_table = cached_links[!duplicated(cached_links), ]
  if (dim(final_table)[1] == 0) {
    cat(paste("\nNo results retrieved, should be invalid subreddit entered, down server or simply unsuccessful search query :("))
  }
  else {
    remove_row = which(final_table[, 1] == "")
    if (length(remove_row) > 0) {
      final_table = final_table[-remove_row, ]
    }
    return(final_table)
  }
}
```

2. extracting the content :

```
reddit_content <- function (URL, wait_time = 1) {

  if (is.null(URL) | length(URL) == 0 | !is.character(URL)) {
    stop("invalid URL parameter")
  }
  GetAttribute = function(node, feature) {
    Attribute = node$data[[feature]]
    replies = node$data$replies
    reply.nodes = if (is.list(replies))
      replies$data$children
    else
      NULL
    return(list(Attribute, lapply(reply.nodes, function(x) {
      GetAttribute(x, feature)
    })))
  }
  get.structure = function(node, depth = 0) {
    if (is.null(node)) {
      return(list())
    }
    filter = is.null(node$data$author)
    replies = node$data$replies
    reply.nodes = if (is.list(replies))
      replies$data$children
    else
      NULL
    return(list(
      paste0(filter, " ", depth),
      lapply(1:length(reply.nodes),
             function(x)
               get.structure(reply.nodes[[x]], paste0(depth,
                                                      "_", x)))
    ))
  }
  data_extract = data.frame(
    id = numeric(),
    structure = character(),
    post_date = as.Date(character()),
    comm_date = as.Date(character()),
    num_comments = numeric(),
    subreddit = character(),
    upvote_prop = numeric(),
    post_score = numeric(),
    author = character(),
    user = character(),
    comment_score = numeric(),
    controversiality = numeric(),
    comment = character(),
    title = character(),
    post_text = character(),
    link = character(),
    domain = character(),
    URL = character()
  )
  withProgress(message = 'Work in progress', value = 0, min=0,max=1, {
  for (i in seq(URL)) {
    if (!grepl("^https?://(.*)", URL[i]))
      URL[i] = paste0("https://www.", gsub("^.*(reddit\\..*$)",
                                           "\\1", URL[i]))
    if (!grepl("\\?ref=search_posts$", URL[i]))
      URL[i] = paste0(gsub("/$", "", URL[i]), "/?ref=search_posts")
    X = paste0(gsub("\\?ref=search_posts$", "", URL[i]),
               ".json?limit=500")
    raw_data = tryCatch(
      RJSONIO::fromJSON(readLines(X, warn = FALSE)),
      error = function(e)
        NULL
    )
    if (is.null(raw_data)) {
      Sys.sleep(min(1, wait_time))
      raw_data = tryCatch(
        RJSONIO::fromJSON(readLines(X,
                                    warn = FALSE)),
        error = function(e)
          NULL
      )
    }
    if (is.null(raw_data) == FALSE) {
      meta.node = raw_data[[1]]$data$children[[1]]$data
      main.node = raw_data[[2]]$data$children
      if (min(length(meta.node), length(main.node)) > 0) {
        structure = unlist(lapply(1:length(main.node),
                                  function(x)
                                    get.structure(main.node[[x]], x)))
        TEMP = data.frame(
          id = NA,
          structure = gsub("FALSE ",
                           "", structure[!grepl("TRUE", structure)]),
          post_date = format(as.Date(
            as.POSIXct(meta.node$created_utc,
                       origin = "1970-01-01")
          ), "%d-%m-%y"),
          comm_date = format(as.Date(
            as.POSIXct(unlist(lapply(main.node,
                                     function(x) {
                                       GetAttribute(x, "created_utc")
                                     })), origin = "1970-01-01")
          ), "%d-%m-%y"),
          num_comments = meta.node$num_comments,
          subreddit = ifelse(
            is.null(meta.node$subreddit),
            "UNKNOWN",
            meta.node$subreddit
          ),
          upvote_prop = meta.node$upvote_ratio,
          post_score = meta.node$score,
          author = meta.node$author,
          user = unlist(lapply(main.node, function(x) {
            GetAttribute(x, "author")
          })),
          comment_score = unlist(lapply(main.node,
                                        function(x) {
                                          GetAttribute(x, "score")
                                        })),
          controversiality = unlist(lapply(main.node,
                                           function(x) {
                                             GetAttribute(x, "controversiality")
                                           })),
          comment = unlist(lapply(main.node, function(x) {
            GetAttribute(x, "body")
          })),
          title = meta.node$title,
          post_text = meta.node$selftext,
          link = meta.node$url,
          domain = meta.node$domain,
          URL = URL[i],
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
        TEMP$id = 1:nrow(TEMP)
        if (dim(TEMP)[1] > 0 & dim(TEMP)[2] > 0)
          data_extract = rbind(TEMP, data_extract)
        else
          print(paste("missed", i, ":", URL[i]))
      }
    }
    incProgress(amount = 1/length(URL))
    Sys.sleep(min(2, wait_time))
  }
  # data_extract[,13] <-
  #   cleaning_text_function(data_extract[,13])
  })
  return(data_extract)
}
```

3. Cleaning the text:

```
cleaning_text_function <- function(x,stopwords=stopwords_vec) {
  stopwords_vec <- c(stopwords::stopwords("en"), "don", "isn", "gt", "i", "re","removed","deleted","m","you re","we ll", "ve", "hasn","they re","id","tl dr", "didn", "wh","oh","tl","dr","shes","hes","aren","edit","ok","ll","wasn","shouldn","t","doesn","youre","going","still","much", "many","also")

  if (is.character(x)) {
    #Put accents instead of code html (only for french)
    Encoding(x) <- 'latin1'
    #take out accent
    x <- stri_trans_general(x, 'latin-ascii')
    x <- unlist(lapply(x, function(x, stopwords = stopwords_vec) {
      #separate words
      x <- unlist(strsplit(x, " "))
      #take out internet links
      x <- x[!grepl("\\S+www\\S+|\\S+https://\\S+|https://\\S+", x)]
      #take out codes ASCII and ponctuation
      x <-gsub("\n|[[:punct:]]|[\x01-\x09\x11-\x12\x14-\x1F\x7F]|gt"," ",x)
      #take out simple alone numbers
      x <-gsub("(^[0-9]{1}\\s|^[0-9]{1}$|\\s{1}[0-9]{1}$|\\s{1}[0-9]{1}\\s{1})"," ",x)
      #take out space in the beginning and end of stringg
      x <-gsub("(^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$)", "", x)
      #lowercase
      x <- tolower(x)
      #take out alone letters
      x <-gsub("(^[a-z]{1}\\s+|^[a-z]{1}$|\\s+[a-z]{1}$|\\s+[a-z]{1}\\s+)", "", x)
      #take out words in stopwords list
      x <-paste(x[!x %in% stopwords], collapse = " ")
      #rerun stopwords again to get ride of stopword in composed string
      x <- unlist(strsplit(x, " "))
      x <-gsub("(^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$)", "", x)
      x <-paste(x[!x %in% stopwords], collapse = " ")
      return(x)
    }))
  } else{
    stop("please enter a character vector")
  }
  return(x)
}
```

And the message we get :

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7745
Warning in file(con, "r") :
  cannot open URL 'https://www.reddit.com/r/news/search.json?q=Greta&restrict_sr=on&t=week&sort=comments': HTTP status was '429 Unknown Error'
Warning: Error in reddit_urls_mod: Unable to connect to reddit website or invalid subreddit entered
  126: stop
  125: reddit_urls_mod
  124: scraping_function
  123: eventReactiveHandler 
   79: df1
   72: observeEventHandler
    1: runApp
```

I get an error 429 even on computers that have never made a request before...

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some more details on how you download / scrape the data. Maybe some code?

Comment: It is possible that you are exceeding the requested quota for the number of hits at that website.  What does the terms of service say?  See this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786068/how-to-avoid-http-error-429-too-many-requests-python

Comment: The terms of service clearly state: "Access, query, or search the Services with any automated system, other than through our published interfaces and pursuant to their applicable terms. However, we conditionally grant permission to crawl the Services for the sole purpose of and solely to the extent necessary for creating publicly available searchable indices of the materials subject to the parameters set forth in our robots.txt file."