# How do i solve HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests?

Tags: python, django, pytube

Iam new to python and making a simple django app to download videos from youtube.It runs withou any error on local host but on production it throws an error :

```
HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

I know its sending too many request in short time but ho do i limit the request?

Comment: `time.sleep` in between a certain amount of calls?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid HTTP error 429 (Too Many Requests) python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786068/how-to-avoid-http-error-429-too-many-requests-python)

Comment: actually this question is different from  [How to avoid HTTP error 429 python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786068/how-to-avoid-http-error-429-too-many-requests-python) 
this problem is because PyTube doesn't use a proper header for request to download media.