# Not getting data from request in python

Tags: python, rest, web-scraping, python-requests

I was trying to fetch a product info from an [online store](https://shop.coles.com.au/a/aspley/product/mutti-tomato-passata-2349503p). It doesn't require any kind of authentication. I can see product information from the browser. I've inspected in developer tools and found the request which fetches data from the [URL](https://shop.coles.com.au/search/resources/store/20520/productview/bySeoUrlKeyword/mutti-tomato-passata-2349503p?catalogId=12064). My python code is bellow

```py
import requests

def coles():
    URL = "https://shop.coles.com.au/search/resources/store/20520/productview/bySeoUrlKeyword/mutti-tomato-passata-2349503p"
    PARAMS = {
        "catalogId": 12064
    }
    res = requests.get(URL,PARAMS)
    print(res.text)


#coles()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    coles()
```

But I'm getting this instead of the product info

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="about:blank">
</head>
<body>
<script src="/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/j.js"></script>
<script src="/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/f.js"></script>
<script src="/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/fingerprint/script/kpf.js?url=/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/fingerprint&token=dcc221cb-d87a-e9e3-5316-7c7a20910bf8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But in the inspection, I got something like this. Maybe I need to add some header information or missing something.
[image]

Here is request info and paramerter
[image: ython]

If I put this [request URL](https://shop.coles.com.au/search/resources/store/20520/productview/bySeoUrlKeyword/mutti-tomato-passata-2349503p?catalogId=12064) in browser I get the data.

Comment: What do get if you run `print(res.status_code)`?

Comment: @ddcastrodd I got 429 in status_code

Comment: That's why you are not getting the data then. 429 is Too Many Requests.

Comment: @ddcastrodd How to prevent from too many requests?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786068/how-to-avoid-http-error-429-too-many-requests-python

Comment: @ddcastrodd  I got a 429 on my very first request. I then tried various User-Agent headers -- no difference.

Comment: @ddcastrodd I've also tried using header. Doesn't work