# avoid 429 error when load multiple images

Tags: html

My webpage need to show about 40 images. For the amount to image to be downloaded from server, it cause 429 error randomly.

I want to guarantee my websites to show all the images for advertisement.
how can I avoid 429 too many requests error? Is there any work around?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid HTTP error 429 (Too Many Requests) python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786068/how-to-avoid-http-error-429-too-many-requests-python)

Comment: Really appreciate your comments, however already saw that but couldn't help me a lot

Comment: what kind of server do you have?

Comment: I use nodejs express as  web App server  and nginx as webserver

Answer (score -1):

I use `lazy loading` to solve this problem.
image won't be requested to server if user not scroll down to image tag itself.

1. First I set `data-src`to  which I want to apply lazy loading.

```
<img data-src="../img2.png" class="lazy"/>
<img data-src="../img2.png" class="lazy"/>
<img data-src="../img2.png" class="lazy"/>
```

2. inject script after body tags.
   here I wrote js script

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        const lazyLoadImages = document.querySelectorAll(".lazy");
        let lazyLoadThrottleTimeout;

        function lazyLoading() {
          if (lazyLoadThrottleTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(lazyLoadThrottleTimeout);
          }

          lazyLoadThrottleTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
            lazyLoadImages.forEach(function (image) {
              if (image.offsetTop < window.innerHeight + scrollTop) {
                image.src = image.dataset.src;
                image.classList.remove("w_lazy");
              }
            });
            if (lazyLoadImages.length) {
              document.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyLoading);
              window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyLoading);
              window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", lazyLoading);
            }
          }, 35);
        }
        document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyLoading);
        window.addEventListener("resize", lazyLoading);
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", lazyLoading);
      });
```

the main idea is eventListener "scroll" and "resize" wait until user scrolling down to image tag, put `src` image path using `data-src`

3. you can use `IntersectionObserver` rather than eventListener, then you will need polyfill for IE user.