# python3.8 google search result in urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests

Tags: python-3.x, google-search, google-search-api

After few tries ... getting following response for google search query as given below. Anybody had solution to this please help?

```
search(query=self.name,tld='com',lang='en',num=100,stop=100,pause=5):
```

> File
> "C:\Users\img_cart_project\venv\lib\site-packages\googlesearch_*init*_.py",
> line 305, in search
> html = get_page(url, user_agent, verify_ssl)   File "C:\Users\img_cart_project\venv\lib\site-packages\googlesearch_*init*_.py",
> line 174, in get_page
> response = urlopen(request)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 222, in urlopen
> return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 531, in open
> response = meth(req, response)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 640, in http_response
> response = self.parent.error(   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 563, in error
> result = self._call_chain(*args)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 502, in _call_chain
> result = func(*args)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 755, in http_error_302
> return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 531, in open
> response = meth(req, response)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 640, in http_response
> response = self.parent.error(   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 569, in error
> return self._call_chain(*args)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 502, in _call_chain
> result = func(*args)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 649, in http_error_default
> raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests

Comment: Please edit your post to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

### Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786068/how-to-avoid-http-error-429-too-many-requests-python).

### Handle the Error in your code

Assuming that you are using the [`google` python package](https://libraries.io/pypi/google) and not the [`google-api-python-client`](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/quickstart/quickstart-python) the line you provided works fine for me.

#### Steps followed

1. Create a clean python environment (using virtualenv in my case, install with pip): `virtualenv google_search_env`
2. Activate the environment: `source google_search_env/bin/activate` for linux or `source google_search_env/scripts/activate` for windows.
3. Install dependencies: `pip install beautifulsoup4 google`
4. Run you python script: `python search_client.py`

```
# search_client.py

from googlesearch import search 

try:
    searche_results = search(query="test search", tld='com',lang='en',num=5,stop=10,pause=1)
    [print("result: "+searche_result) for searche_result in searche_results]
except HTTPError:
    print("429 HTTP Error.")
    # more code...
except:
    print("There was an issue while fetching results.")
```

This should print search results for `test search` term or the custom exception.