# Webscraping: getting lenght of imgur video

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Good morning! I recently have been trying to web scrape the imgur website of a hosted video, in particular the video length, as you can see in the image. I tried all the imaginable possible ways (be via python autiful soup, requests library, etc) to get this data, but everytime I do it, or I receive a html file that has nothing do with the data I need, or a completely blank response. I can´t use selenium since the code needs to run in heroku, so I don´t have any idea on how to do this. Thanks to all who spare some time helping me! [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK2Hs.png)

Comment: It's __Webscraping__ not webscrapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the network tab, you will see that `imgur` provides [api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZxgi.jpg) for each post. So, instead of scraping website itself, you can work on api to get desired output:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://api.imgur.com/post/v1/media/xsmX53B?client_id=<your_client_id>&include=media%2Cadconfig%2Caccount'
response_json = requests.get(url).json()
```

This will get you:

```
{"id":"xsmX53B","account_id":0,"title":"","description":"","view_count":642,"upvote_count":0,"downvote_count":0,"point_count":0,"image_count":1,"comment_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"virality":0,"score":0,"in_most_viral":false,"is_album":false,"is_mature":false,"cover_id":"xsmX53B","created_at":"2021-03-08T16:51:58Z","updated_at":null,"url":"https://imgur.com/xsmX53B","privacy":"","vote":null,"favorite":false,"is_ad":false,"ad_type":0,"ad_url":"","include_album_ads":false,"shared_with_community":false,"is_pending":false,"platform":"api","ad_config":{"show_ads":false,"safe_flags":["not_in_gallery","share"],"high_risk_flags":[],"unsafe_flags":["sixth_mod_unsafe"],"wall_unsafe_flags":[]},"media":[{"id":"xsmX53B","account_id":0,"mime_type":"video/mp4","type":"video","name":"","basename":"","url":"https://i.imgur.com/xsmX53B.mp4","ext":"mp4","width":960,"height":540,"size":14009178,"metadata":{"title":"","description":"","is_animated":true,"is_looping":true,"duration":59.92,"has_sound":false},"created_at":"2021-03-08T16:51:58Z","updated_at":null}],"display":[]}
```

Now you can scrape duration from json file easily:

```
duration = response_json['media'][0]['metadata']['duration']
```

*Note that* I hid my `client_id`; therefore, don't forget to change it to yours. Finally, `duration` will look like this:

```
59.92
```

Comment: Thank you, really. I have been hours and hours in this without finding anything. Just a question: do I really need a client id? I tried to get the json without it and it was working...

Comment: I haven't checked specifically for imgur but some api's show result only for authenticated users, so it is better to include it. If you didn't face any problems, then it is fine

Comment: Just tried it. If I use it in python I get a 429 error saying I exceed the limit so I guess I really need do it. Really thanks!

Comment: Note that 429 error is not authentication error. It means you have sent numerous requests to website so they blocked you for some time. Try not to spam it :)

Comment: Its quite interesting I can still use the search engine to get the data but when I use python I always get that error.

Comment: check this thread for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786068/how-to-avoid-http-error-429-too-many-requests-python#:~:text=Receiving%20a%20status%20429%20is,not%20willing%20to%20accept%20this.