# Scrapy spider returning error 429 after around 727 scraped pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a Scrapy spider to scrape a list of 3,000 URLs. Whether I scrape them slowly (0.8 sites per second) or a little faster (1.5 sites per second), the spider always starts failing after scraping around 727 pages, returning error 429. Funnily enough, I have shuffled the URLs and out of the 10 times I reran it, for 3 of those it scraped exactly 727 items and the remaining times around 690-730, to then start returning 429 errors.

I am using headers, random proxies and random user agents for each request. Has somebody experienced something like this?

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
import json
import csv
import re
import random


class website(scrapy.Spider): 

    name = "website"

    country_id = 'US'  

    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_ITEMS': 40,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 20,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 20,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.9,
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
        'RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY': True,

        'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
        'FEEDS': {
            f'data/{name}.jl': {
                "format": "jsonlines"
            }
        }
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self.headers = {
                        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
                        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
                        "cache-control": "no-cache",
                        "pragma": "no-cache",
                        "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
                        "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
                        "sec-fetch-site": "none",
                        "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
                        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
                        }
        
        with open('data/missing_website_data_urls.txt') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            for row in csv_reader:
                self.missing_website_data_urls = row
        
        
    def start_requests(self):
        for search_url in self.missing_website_data_urls:
            search_url = search_url[:32] + re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z ]+', '', search_url[32:])
            #search_url = search_url.replace('&', '').replace('$', '').replace('+', '').replace(',', '').replace('/', '').replace('?', '').replace('=', '').replace('@', '').replace(':', '').replace(';', '')
            yield scrapy.Request(url=search_url,
                                 method='GET',
                                 headers=self.headers,
                                 callback=self.parse,
                                 cb_kwargs={'url': search_url},
                                 meta={'proxy_country': self.country_id
                                       }
                                )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid HTTP error 429 (Too Many Requests) python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786068/how-to-avoid-http-error-429-too-many-requests-python)

Comment: @Sören, no. I implemented something like that for the retries, but, again, it starts failing after 727 successful requests. Also, the additional part that calls my attention is why it fails after the same number of successful scrapes

Answer (score 0):

You haven't supplied code, but from what you've stated in your question, it appears that you are being fingerprinted with either a modern fingerprinting library such as [fingerprint.js](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs) or you forgot to clear your cookies (refreshing your session).

Comment: I just added my code. I was thinking the same, but, if that were the case, why if I stop and rerun my code immediately, it then works? I can stop it and run it 10 seconds later and it again scrapes up to 727-730 stores.

Comment: This is probably specific to the website you are scraping. Unless you add the website, I'm not sure anyone can help you figure it out.